Manuscript rejected after all reviewers indicate it is "good match" to publish in journal. Is this common?
Just got a surprising rejection from an IEEE journal. For the following question in the reviewer form (which is usually the last one to give their overall recommendation I think), all 3 reviewers have responded as:
"How would you rate the appropriateness of this paper for publication in this IEEE Transactions?: good match"
One reviewer attached a PDF with their feedback and explicitly proposed that the paper be published in the journal.
Some reviewers have raised usual minor questions/feedback and kindly offered "some relevant" papers to be added to my reference list, the normal stuff that can be addressed in a revision. Nothing major like incorrect methodology, more study/simulations needed, extend it like this, that is wrong, etc. Nothing.
Email from AE: Your paper has merit, but based on reviews is not recommended for publication. Recommend you to improve based on reviewer comments and send elsewhere.
No other reason given. No rebuttal/response, no major revision/minor revision, no reject and resubmit. I know some IEEE journals only do accept/reject, but this is not one of them.
Is it the right IEEE journal to send to? I should think so because the reviewers seem to think so also by saying it is a good match, and because it has published papers in exactly the same field before.

Is this common? Has anyone else had this experience (i.e. reviewers unanimously saying the paper is a good match to publish but still a rejection from AE)?

Is it any use to request clarification/appeal? If so, should I write up a rebuttal for the reviewers feedback as well and attach that, in the hopes that if there WAS anything from the reviews that led to the decision, I would have a response to it? Or is that just a waste of time?



“Good match” means it’s in scope, but doesn’t say whether it is a good or interesting paper. They might have been asked to privately indicate whether to accept or reject the paper and might have recommended rejection due to it simply not being significant or interesting enough.

@Significance, the feedback is as I've mentioned in my question: "How would you rate the appropriateness of this paper for publication in this IEEE Transactions?: good match" . I don't see the question asking about scope. Would it be appropriate for publication if it wasn't good or interesting? And none of the other feedback really says it isn't.

@Significance, also if we assume somehow that "good match" refers to scope, why is the AE suggesting that I improve the paper and submit it "elsewhere" to a different journal? If the issue was the interestingness or goodness of it by adding more studies, etc, a "reject and resubmit" could've been given, where I am asked to make it more interesting/good and resubmit it.

@CWT It's reasonable to suggest things to improve a paper but the interestingness is a bit more core to the project (plus a heavy influence of external factors). If you could have made the paper more interesting that's absolutely something you should have done before submission.

@BryanKrause, fair enough. Though I am suggesting a new mathematical model in my paper, so exploring additional more interesting applications could have been a feedback maybe to hint at that. However, none of the reviews (which at least are visible to me, unless something was said in private) have said that it is not interesting. And even acknowledging that interestingness cannot be improved, surely the question "How would you rate the appropriateness of this paper for publication in this IEEE Transaction?" would encompass this aspect.

@DanielR.Collins, I have seen that question before posting mine, however I think the context is quite different. The manuscript in that question is related to expanding a conference proceeding paper and submitting it to a journal's special issue. One answer points out that this could have been the cause of the rejection. My manuscript was for a regular paper. I was wondering if anyone in the community has faced this, how common it is and what their experience was (the poster of that question certainly has faced it in regards to an extended conference paper submission to a special issue).

@CWT It's not the reviewers' job to find interesting applications of your model.

@BryanKrause, did you read my comment? I said that if they felt it was not interesting, providing feedback like "author needs to explore more interesting applications of proposed model" could be a hint at the paper not being interesting enough. I did NOT say it is their job to find interesting applications for my model - I am sufficiently aware that it isn't.

@CWT That's still not their job. They're evaluating the paper in front of them. That's a big enough job without proposing ways to make it more interesting or imaging a different paper that could be in front of them but is not.

@CWT It may not be the applications but the model itself that they find not sufficiently interesting. You’ve quoted comments like “slightly novel”, which suggests that is indeed the problem. If the model itself is not more than slightly novel, though there isn’t anything inherently wrong with it, then “reject and encourage submitting to a journal with lower standards for novelty” is the only sensible decision. There’s nothing they can ask you to fix or improve: it’s just not interesting/novel enough.

@BryanKrause, not sure why you are fixated on telling me what their job is while I am trying to understand the feedback they have given. I am saying they have not mentioned the manuscript is interesting either directly or indirectly (by suggesting the author try different applications). You say the latter isn't their job (not that I said it was, I am saying that feedback wasn't provided whether it was their job or not). But great if it isn't. Is the former at least not their job? I.e. to directly say the paper isn't interesting enough to be published? Because that wasn't done either.

Typo in comment: I am saying they have not mentioned the manuscript is *not interesting either directly or indirectly...

@CWT Reviewers are very unlikely to say that a a paper isn’t interesting enough because there isn’t much that authors can do to fix that, so it’s just mean. Rating a paper as only “slightly novel”, though is a fairly direct way of saying the same thing.

@Significance, the reviewer who has said "The paper has new and interesting results and I propose that it be published in this journal, but some concerns to address are..." is one of the reviewers who have said it is "slightly novel", so maybe it is an indirect way of saying uninteresting, maybe it isn't, I don't know. Just a personal opinion: it would be so much more helpful if reviewers were direct, clear, to the point rather than excessively polite. Getting rejected without a clear reason/critique seems meaner and more personal than getting rejected with one.

My guess is that the editor has decided your paper is not as interesting as other submissions and suggests you try a journal with a lower impact.  If you agree, you can send to a lower-impact journal.  If you disagree, you can send to another journal at this level or higher.
If you are not getting rejections some of the time, you are not submitting to high-enough journals.  Rejections are a normal part of academic life.  Be glad that our rage and disappointment is not televised, as in "the agony of defeat" at the Olympics.  Find a void into which to scream.  Learn how long your rage lasts.  Wait it out. Then resubmit elsewhere.
Appeals are generally a waste of time.  They consume months with a low probability of success.  The exception is if the review process was really bad.  Like an experimental paper sent to three theoreticians for review or a reviewer commenting on a version of the manuscript that does not match the submitted version.

Thanks Terry. Appreciate your answer about the likelihood of a successful appeal. It indirectly answers my second question about whether I should reach out to the AE for clarification and whether I should write a rebuttal of whatever feedback the reviewers have given. I suspected it wasn't worth the effort and your answer has helped me decide that.

This is definitely not common. If all the reviewers are positive, odds are your manuscript is accepted as well. But it can happen.
Assuming they're responsive & the reviews are as positive as you think they are (are they actually positive, as opposed to merely not negative?), there's no harm done in asking them if they didn't make a mistake. They could for example have sent the wrong decision or editor comments. If they say no, you can still submit elsewhere.

Thanks for your answer. Regarding novelty, I don't see any major concerns raised: "Sufficiently novel", "Although paper is interesting, some concerns to be addressed are...", "Slightly novel", "New and interesting results, I propose it be published", "Somewhat novel", "Slightly novel". I don't see any reviewer outright saying it is not novel or interesting, two have actually said it IS interesting. The third has called it "a smooth paper" (I'm guessing that's praise?).
Should I write up a response to the reviewer feedback and sending it? Honestly feel disheartened and think it'll be a waste.

I am not sure that all the referees' comments were positive, but you might be right.  I think some of them were damning by faint praise. I think the OP needs to talk to someone in their research area.  The conventions of referee reports vary greatly by area.

Yes, as @TerryLoring comments, a superficially polite way of being negative is to "damn by faint praise"... without being helpful or constructive in any way.

@CWT So you got four reviews? With 2x"Slightly Novel" and 1x"Somewhat novel" it's quite likely that the editor decided not to go forward with your paper because the papers that they end up publishing get better ratings. It may not look like a major concern to you, but if the competition is better, it actually is.

Four reviews isn't common.  It suggests that the editor sent it out to an additional reviewer after getting mixed reviews.

@DCTLib, to clarify, not 4 reviews. I just listed whatever was written with the word "novel", one reviewer has mentioned "somewhat novel" in his written review as well. But I take your point that my manuscript could have lost out to competition. Thanks.
